# Share global Unity Container between two assemblies without passing a reference

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have two assemblies:

- SERVICE - with interfaces for repositories
- DB - with repository implementation

The reference direction is from DB to SERVICE (DB references SERVICE).

The SERVICE assembly creates a Unity Container. It will load DB assembly dynamically during runtime (to load implementation).

Now I need to register repository objects in the DB assembly, but I can't find any way retrieve already created Unity Container in DB assembly (instead of creating a new one what has different context).

The question is (possible solution): is there any way to get a list of already created Containers in current AppDomain (to share between asms)

I don't want to use lookup (discovery), like this:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
  WithName.Default);
```

Because I want my bindings to be explicit.

Comment: So SERVICE and DB are class libraries, right? Where are you using them? Is there an application that uses them in the same solution? Or is your project a component that has class libraries only?

Comment: For the sake of example I stripped information that there is a console application that references the SERVICE. Yes, everything is in the one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question but... I discovered that there are no such feature in Unity.

Possible solutions:

- if assembly is referenced statically - a bootstrap method has to be invoke with reference to container, e.g. UnityConfig.Register(container);
- if assembly is loaded dynamically (plugin) without any static references. Invoke the code presented in the question itself, i.e.:

---

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
  WithName.Default);
```

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't use (or even reference) the DI container in any of `SERVICE` or `DB` class libraries. The only place where the container should be used is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

The Composition Root is the entry point in an application. In your case, it is the `main` method of the Console Application. This is where you compose the classes from all the class libraries by registering types with the container and resolving your objects (usually a single root object).

Your class libraries shouldn't have Composition Roots. Only applications have Composition Roots. This allows other applications to use these class libraries while using different DI containers, or even without using any (which is called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)).

Comment: Sounds ok for monolithic applications. But:
1) There's a 'dependency inversion' patten between SERVICE and DB. You suggest making a circular reference.
2) What would be the point in abstracting interfaces when the root application would still have to connect interface with implementation? This way I could just ignore interfaces and use concrete types everywhere. Even so, implementations ain't public.
3) Central point of "registration" sounds like a monolithic anti-pattern with all-knowing-master class.
4) Anyway, I don't know which implementation of DB is going to be loaded until runtime.

Comment: @andrew.fox, for (1) Why is there a circular dependency? as you said, DB depends on SERVICE, and now COMPOSITIONROOT Depends on both DB and SERVICE. There is no circular dependency.

Comment: For (2), you still need to have interfaces since you want to replace dependencies in the future. For example, for dependency IDependency that is injected into SomeClass, today you are using DependencyA. In the future you will go to the composition root and change it to DependencyB.

Comment: For (3), the Composition Root does not have to be a single class. It can be multiple classes in a single project. But yes, it has to know everything. Composition Roots constitute applications. Your application needs to know about all the classes to be able to compose them together.

Comment: For (4), that is a different concern, there are some patterns to solve this. For example, the abstract factory pattern.

Comment: (3) and (4) - my question comes from req to have a loosely coupled application architecture. I know how to do it "by code", Ninject was never a problem too. But the question is not about patterns but how to make it easily with Unity Container.

Comment: You still have loose coupling if you use the container in the Composition Root only. If fact, your system would be more loosely coupled this way. What is your concern with moving all of the registrations to the Composition Root? In any case, if you decide to have local registrations for each library (which I am recommending that you not do), you can simply create some LocalCompositionRoot for each library that takes in a unity container and does some registrations, then you would call such local composition roots from the application it self passing the container.

Comment: Thinking about it, why not move these LocalCompositionRoot(s) from the individual libraries to the Composition Root application?

Comment: Because of a good ol' "Dependency inversion principle"... But I didn't share all other architecture requirements with you, so discussing it this way won't be productive. For the time being I'm going to assume that Unity have no such feature I can use.